# Assigning a different output value than what is shown on UIPickerView

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview

I've searched all throughout yesterday on this website for an answer to this, but I haven't been able to find this. I'm an amateur coder, really just doing this for a small organization to see if we can help improve processes.

Here is what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to make an app that allows someone to select an account number, a task, and then it will output a numerical number for a full account number that they can put on receipts.

For example, someone selects account number 12345678910 and they select "cleaning the bathroom". I want the app to spit out a full account number like 12345678910 58392, where 58932 is associated with "cleaning the bathroom", but is not actually shown on the PickerView. I've been having trouble with this. Coding is something I've always wanted to learn, but have been doing it on my own time, so please forgive the amateur like mistakes if any. I've been using YouTube videos for this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much!
[Sample app screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQX4X.png)

```
import UIKit

class Account {
    var account: String
    var jlCode: [String]

    init(account:String, jlCode:[String]) {
        self.jlCode = jlCode
        self.account = account
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var accountLbl: UILabel!

    var accounts = [Account]()

    @IBAction func showPopup(_ sender: Any) {
        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)

        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)

        popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

        //This area will have to be changed once you get the right information.

        accounts.append(Account(account: "12345678910", jlCode: ["task 1", "task 2", "task 3", "task 4"]))
        accounts.append(Account(account: "1112131415", jlCode: ["Task 1"]))
        accounts.append(Account(account: "1617181920", jlCode: ["task 1", "task 2", "task 3", "task 4"]))
        accounts.append(Account(account: "2122232425", jlCode: ["task 1", "task 2", "task 3", "task 4"]))

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            return accounts.count
        } else {
            let selectedAccount = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
            return accounts[selectedAccount].jlCode.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            return accounts[row].account
        } else {
            let selectedAccount = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
            return accounts[selectedAccount].jlCode[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        pickerView.reloadComponent(1)

        let selectedAccount = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let selectedjlCode = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        let account = accounts[selectedAccount].account
        let jlCode = accounts[selectedAccount].jlCode[selectedjlCode]

        accountLbl.text = "Account Number: \(account)\nJL Code: \(jlCode)"
    }
}
```

Comment: "where 58932 is associated with "cleaning the bathroom", but is not actually shown on the PickerView" OK, but where _is_ it shown? I don't see any association between 58932 and "cleaning the bathroom" in your code. You need to store this association between task names and task account numbers somewhere in your code; the computer does not know about it by reading your mind.

Comment: Will task 1 always be "office supplies" and task 2 always be "water"? Or will the list of tasks be totally different between accounts?

Comment: Hi guys, there will be different tasks for each account number that will also have their own unique numerical value. I’m having trouble associating a value to each respective task that will later be outputted to the user - I’m not sure how. So for account number 12345678910, there will be a unique task 1. Task 1 will have also have a unique code that isn’t displayed (the reason for the app is so that these numbers are automatically sent to the user - to avoid mixups in paperwork; hope this makes sense), but will later be once the user clicks “get my account number”.

Comment: Ideally, in the app picture, I’d like the PickerView to say “water”, but for the JL code to actually read some value that I assign to it. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, and that is a big **IF**, I understand you correctly your problem is that you have nothing connecting the *description* of the task with the numeric value associated with the task. In other words it seems your simply struggling with the modelling of your data.

I would think something like the below might help you in the right direction:

```
struct Account {
    var number: Int
    var tasks: [Task]

    var description: String { return "\(number)" }
}

struct Task {
    var number: Int // or JLNumber, or whatever you want to call it
    var description: String
}
```

That would leave you setting up Accounts like this:

```
let account = Account(number: 12345678910, tasks: [Task(number: 58932, description: "Cleaning the bathroom")])
```

You would display the `.description` in the pickerView, and use the `.number` wherever that makes sense.

If the different *type* of tasks are *predefined*, (i. e. they will never change without the code being changed) you should have a look at `enums` rather than creating them on the fly with strings and integers...

Comment: Thank you so much. As someone that is new to coding, I obviously didn’t know this was possible but opens a lot of new possibilities. I will probably have a somewhat related question soon!

Comment: You're more than welcome. I'd appreciate if you'd mark my answer helpful and/or accepted though if you think it warrants it.  :-)

Comment: Sure thing! I’m new to this website, but I think I did I